# Excel VBA C++ .dll

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll

First post here.  I'm trying to follow the numerous tutorials out there for compiling a C++ dll as an Excel function and running it as an Excel function, but can't seem to get it to work.  I'm running Windows 10 64-bit, Visual Studio Community 2017, and Excel 2016 64-bit.

I've followed the tutorials out there.  I started a new project as a "Windows Desktop Wizard", and created an empty project as a DLL.  This is my code below. 
 There are only these two files, in the "Source Files" folder under my project.

funct.cpp:

```
double __stdcall squareFxn(double x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

This is my Def file, defFile.def:

```
LIBRARY "square"
EXPORTS
squareFxn
```

In the project properties, I made sure to set the Platform to x64 in the configuration manager, and added "defFile.def" without quotes to Linker/Input/Module Definition File.

It compiled fine.  I put the following into VBA:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function squareFxn Lib "C:\MyPath\square.dll" (ByVal x As Double) As Double
```

When I debugged in Visual Studio, and ran in an Excel cell:

```
=squareFxn(5)
```

Visual studio is saying that x is an extremely small number (6.234E-310) and the function is returning zero.

The other problem I'm having is when I try to do this as a reference, with the appropriate changes (squareFxn(double &x) in funct.cpp and ByRef instead of ByVal in the VBA function declaration), I'm getting a read access error.  I tried running Excel as an administrator, to no avail.

Does anybody know what's going on here?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I'm using this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3WWA8eEX9Q

Note, that video is for 32 bit excel, hence me setting the platform to x64 in the compiler and my use of the "PtrSafe" keyword.

Any way you can upload your solution project?  Maybe it's some weird setting in my version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I just tried running this in a Macro:

`Sub TestSquare()

    Dim A As Double
    Dim ASquared As Double
    
    
    A = 5
    ASquared = squareFxn(A)
    


End Sub`

And it's working in a Macro, so it's just calling it as a function in a worksheet that's having an issue.  Not sure if that helps your diagnosis.  I guess I can always write an "intermediate" macro, and call that from the worksheet, which then calls the .dll.

Comment: Whilst the video is interesting, I think you need to get into creating self-registering dlls which have file extension xll.  So Microsoft docs here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687883.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687861.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll look into .xll.  I had 2 source files because when creating the empty .dll project, it didn't come with any.  I tried the above instructions again with a non-empty .dll file.  I now see the dllmain.cpp, stdafx.h, and stfafx.cpp files.  I'm getting the exact same result, but it works running through a Macro, so I'll just use a wrapper.  Out of curiosity, what do these three files do?  I've done a ton of MATLAB and VBA but am new to C++.  Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.

Comment: I have started from scratch with an empty project and it still works for me.  Sorry.

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you able to get the reference version (with the call squareFxn(double &x)  ) working?  Even when I call it from a Macro, it still gives the 6.234E-310 number.  I played around with variable types, trying long instead of double, and it gave me a crazy high number, something in the hundred millions.  Is this an error of converting a VBA double to a C++ double?

Comment: Using ampersand works from VBA but not from sheet. Worksheet functions would need to be registered if you want to use reference types, here is a table (from Excel SDK) showing possible pass by ref parameter types which I find surprising https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687900.aspx#languageReferenceRemarksToggle

Comment: Finally at 3AM, I said f*** it, and installed Visual Studio 2013.  Guess what, now the references work :D.  I tried it out this morning on clean installs of Visual Studio Express 2013 and Visual Studio Community 2017, same results.  Is there some weird setting in the default install of Visual Studio 2017 that makes it compile incorrectly?  Also, I'm planning on deploying this spreadsheet to computers using Excel 2010 and later; does the year of Visual Studio need to be earlier than the year of Excel, or how does that work?  Thanks so much by the way, you've been a huge help!

Comment: Ugh...nope.  I tried a new function similar to the above with three input arguments.  The first one gets the correct reference.  The second and third are returning references to wrong numbers (-9E61, -6E-130).  Is this a compiler issue you think?

Comment: Sounds like uninitialised memory, memory contains random garbage, languages like VBA initialise memory to zeroes or some default..

Comment: What's the best workaround?  I went back to one argument (identical to above) in VSExpress 2013 and am now getting the same garbage as before with VS 2017 (-6.234E-310).  Is there a way to force memory initialization in VBA before the number/string is passed to the C++ dll?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I'd like to collaborate, perhaps you should start a public repository on Github.  Incidentally, why do you need references to a primitive?

Comment: Just put the repository up: https://github.com/markl413/ReferenceTest .  I am going to end up needing references for when I'm passing arrays, etc; I figured I'd get the issue resolved on something simple like this before moving to the advanced stuff.  Also, I'm back to references not working at all with VS2013...really bizarre behavior.  Curious, do you have a 64 bit version of excel you can test it on?

Answer (score 1):

You might need a wrapper function in VBA in order to cast the Variant (14 bytes) representing a cell to a Double (8 bytes). At least, this works in my situation: VSE2017, x64 DLL-build together with XL2016x64. For example:

in CPP:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double __cdecl myCPPfunc(double x)
{
    return some_double_expression;
}
```

in VBA:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function myVBAfunc Lib "complete_path_to_my.DLL" Alias "myCPPfunc" (ByVal x As Double) As Double

Function WS_myVBAfunc(ByVal x#)
Dim result#
result = myVBAfunc(x)
WS_myVBAfunc = result
End Function
```

You would also want to modify WS_myVBAfunc so that it accepts and returns an entire range of cells. This speeds up the whole process considerably.